# Line behind text on H1 tag

Tags: text, line, behind

I need to create line behind text. I have check many propositions from google but nothing is working.

I have screenshot, what I need to do.

Really thanks for help :)[image]

Comment: Have you tried some kind of layout application? What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: I am using only clear CSS and HTML. Do not question about what does this have to do with programming... help or do not answear. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want help, why are you even posting here?

Comment: I want help, but you ask fot stupid questions.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention HTML or CSS even once. How are people supposed to know that's what you're using?

Comment: Ok, sorry my fault... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly your answer , if you want to add a line like that to your page behind text , you can add it as png image and set its location with css style

```
position : absolute ;
left : 20px;
top : 20px;
```

change values until it takes its right place

I hope that helps

Comment: This is a solution, but maybe a way to do this with CSS?

Comment: this is the code<html>
<center>HELLO WORLD!</center>
<img src="1.png" style="position : absolute; left : 500px; 
top : 20px; z-index : -1;">  change numbers in left and top

Comment: No, I dont need html code or positioning it in CSS, bit maybe there is solution like styling underline or border-bottom :) but thanks for help :)

Comment: <font style="border-bottom : solid; border-color : 
yellow;">HELLO WORLD</font> .... just a line

Comment: Yeah, I can do border-bottom but I need style like on image :)